# Using regex_search

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to parse some text to figure out if it's a link or not.  This is the code I have:

```
    smatch m;
    regex e("http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+");
    bool match = regex_search(proto->message, m, e);
    if(match == true) {
        chan->Say("Matched link");
    }
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
/main.cpp|26|error: no matching function for call to ‘regex_search(char [1024], boost::smatch&, boost::regex&)’|
```

When I take the m out of `regex_search` it works and returns a `boolean`, but I want know what the actual match was.

Comment: why do you not use `#include<regex>`, `std::smatch`, and `std::regex`  ?

Comment: @Julius Maybe because GCC doesn’t implement them?

Comment: When I include regex.h I get "regex" isn't defined in this scoop.  When I include regex I get a compile error simply for including it.

Answer (score 1):

Boost's regex_search does not define such a signature that you're trying to use. In none of the overloads is boost::smatch the second parameter. In fact, smatch isn't used at all. See [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/regex_search.html) and in particular the example at the bottom of the page.